# Point to different jdk versio in bash to run java program

Tags: java

I am trying to run java program in linux and the current version installed is 1.5 and I want to run using 1.7 jdk.

What I did so far is in bash,

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Myhome/java/java1.7/
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin
EXPORT PATH
```

After executing above, when I type which java, it is still pointing to old version (1.5).

I do not want to modify what is /user/bin/java, but just want to point to the newer version for my testing.

Anyone can help how I can change this?

Thanks.

Comment: how are you running your java program?

Comment: I am using ant to run build.xml

Comment: Try `which java` If it shows you anything but `/Myhome/java/java1.7/bin/java` you haven't set the PATH correctly.

Comment: Are you sure that ant isn't using the version that you want? You can print what ant is using from within your build.xml using the echo task. Add: `<echo message="java version: ${ant.java.version}"/>` at the top of build.xml right after the `project` tag

Answer (score 0):

You need to confugire alternatives. For rexample:

```
# alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/bin/java 100
# alternatives --install /usr/bin/javaws javaws /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/bin/javaws 100
# alternatives --install /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so libjavaplugin.so
                  /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/jre/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so 100
```

change paths to your JDK